# Question about hereditary separability

Tags: general-topology

If we have the clousure of a metric space $\overline{X}$ and we know that $X$ is separable (so in fact it's hereditarily separable), can we say that $\overline{X}$ is hereditarily separable too?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is $X$ your space? If so, $\overline{X}=X$.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that $X$ is a separable metric space that is a subspace of some space $Y$, and you want to know whether $\operatorname{cl}_YX$ is hereditarily separable? If so, the answer is *not necessarily*: the countably infinite discrete space $\Bbb N$ is separable, metrizable, and dense in the space $\beta\Bbb N$, which is not hereditarily separable. In fact, $\beta\Bbb N\setminus\Bbb N$ contains $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$ pairwise disjoint non-empty open sets, so it certainly isn’t separable.